# Which is better, xCode 7.0.1 or xCode 7.1.1

Tags: xcode

I have xcode 7.0.1 and there is new version of it which is 7.1.1. However, I checked mac store and it received many bad ratings so. Its better to stay with 7.0.1 or 7.1.1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's Gorilla vs Shark (sort of) https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Comment: always get the latest version.

Comment: Well, it's 0.1 newer.  If you need that extra 0.1, then go for it.  (You see, most blokes, you know, will be coding at 7.0.1.  You're on 7.0.1 here, all the way up, all the way up, all the way up, you're on 7.0.1 on your computer. Where can you go from there? Where? Nowhere. Exactly. What we do is, if we need that extra push over the cliff, you know what we do? Put it to 7.1.1.  Exactly.  0.1 more.)

Answer (score 1):

You can rename 7.0.1 to something, stick it on your desktop and then download 7.1.1 and then put them both in your applications folder and test them both out. The biggest addition to 7.1 was tvOS so if you aren't doing anything for that then stay with 7.0.1 until you are comfortable moving up to 7.1.1.